# How to find mass of the solid S bounded by the elliptic paraboloid $z=x^2+4y^2$ and plane $z=a$ ($a>0$) if $S$ has a constant density $K$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the mass of the solid  $S$ bounded by the elliptic paraboloid $z  = x^2 + 4y^2$ and plane $z =  a$ ($a > 0$) if $S$ has a constant density $K$.

Comment: Since density is constant then just find $V$ and the mass is $m=K V$.

Comment: Setting up the interval is what I am having trouble with. I know the final answer should be m = (1/4)*(a^2)*pi.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps help you to solve the problem

1) $x^2 + 4 y^2 \leq z \leq a$.

2) the region in $xy$-plane follows from the equation

$$ x^2 + 4 y^2 =a .$$